# Use fabric to test only authentication

Tags: python, fabric

I have so many servers but the ldap system looks not reliable so I want to test if I can login to servers. I'm trying to use fabric to do this job like this:

```
env.user = username
env.host_string = host
print 'Testing %s ...' % host
with settings(hide('warnings', 'running', 'stdout', 'stderr'), warn_only = True, abort_on_prompts = True):
    dir = run('pwd')
    if dir:
        print dir
```

Is there any approach to just test the authentication without 'run'?

Comment: You can use paramiko (which fabric relies in) to test just a simple connection on SSH

Comment: Good suggestion! I was too lazy and want to fabric solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a for loop in bash?

```
for CHECK_HOST in $(xargs < newline_delimited_host_strings)
do
    ssh $CHECK_HOST exit || echo "$CHECK_HOST failed" && echo "$CHECK_HOST worked"
done
```

Comment: Thank you it looks good but I'm using this to check the login credential.

Comment: I don't understand, what is this doing that you don't want?